# Is $\log(y^2)=e^{-x}$ a function of $x$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I need to determine whether $\log(y^2)=e^{-x}$ is a function of $x$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm. 
And I have come up with two conflicting answers:

1. $\log(y^2)=e^{-x} \, \Rightarrow \, 2 \log(y)=e^{-x} \, \Rightarrow \, y=e^{\frac{e^{-x}}{2}}$
2. $\log(y^2)=e^{-x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=e^{e^{-x}} \, \Rightarrow \, y = \pm \sqrt{e^{e^{-x}}}$

From the (1) I would conclude it is a function and from (2) I would conclude that it is not. 
Where is my flaw?

Thanks!

Comment: it miss an absolute value...

Comment: Keep in mind $\sqrt{e^x} = e^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Comment: Equation $\log(y^2) = 2 \log y$ may be true, but when $y<0$ it is better to keep all values real by writing $\log(y^2) = 2\log(-y)$.

Comment: I would have asked: Given $\log(y^2)=e^{-x}$, is $y$ a function of $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the same thing. A fractional power is a root.

But your conclusion is sound. There are 2 values of y.